# Odoo module, js models ignore the inherited function definition

Tags: javascript, inheritance, odoo

I have this odoo module pos_dusal that has a loyalty program.
the module, creates a loyalty program that add to each product sold on  point of sale a certain numbers of loyalty points to the customer, so that he can later exchange them to gifts...

I tried to inherit it and add custom bonus rules such as when reached 1000 loyalty points we give the customer a 10 % of the points so on. Everything works well, but when I validate the order, the original module ignores my modification even though I call it using the same process they do.

Here is the object order in the original view

```js
var models = require('point_of_sale.models');

var _super = models.Order;
    var my_model = models.Order.extend({
    finalize: function(){
            var client = this.get_client();
            if ( client ) {
                console.log("\n +finalize super : ");
                client.loyalty_points =this.get_new_total_points();
            // The client list screen has a cache to avoid re-rendering
            // the client lines, and so the point updates may not be visible ...
            // We need a better GUI framework !
            this.pos.gui.screen_instances.clientlist.partner_cache.clear_node(client.id);
        }
        _super.prototype.finalize.apply(this,arguments);
    },
});
```

it calls the finalize function of the point of sales module,
so, here is what I did, I redefined all the functions used and also finalize() but while i call the super function, Mine'effects are overrided by the original one.

```js
var models = require('point_of_sale.models');

var super_dusal_order = models.Order;
    models.Order = models.Order.extend({
    finalize: function(){
        var client = this.get_client();
        if ( client ) {
            console.log("\n ++++ custom.loyalty.program finalize function ++++");

                // The client list screen has a cache to avoid re-rendering
                // the client lines, and so the point updates may not be visible ...
                // We need a better GUI framework !

                client.loyalty_points = this.get_new_total_points();
                this.pos.gui.screen_instances.clientlist.partner_cache.clear_node(client.id);
            }
            super_dusal_order.prototype.finalize.apply(this,arguments);
        },
    });
```

I don't know why we are using prototype instead of super(), and why does calling the super model finalize method override mine and not the contrary?

Regards

Comment: Finally, resolved the problem, 
And of course the prototype function will call the super function using the passed parameters, so it ignores the one currently defined in the model.